# Postgres update query causing Lock Wait to spike up

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

So I have a table:

```
Resource(rm_id::UUID, resource_id::UUID, available::boolean, date::Date, node_id::varchar, start_time::varchar, end_time::varchar, created_at: DateTime, updated_at: DateTime)
```

So, I am consuming some resource update events from a topic from GCP.
I have 2 kind of events, resource_availability and resource_unavailability events.

Event Data

```
(resource_id, date, available, start_time, end_time)
```

So whenever a event comes up irrespective of checking whether the record exists or not, what i do is execute this query

```
update resource set available = :available, updated_at = :updatedAt where resource_id = :someId AND date = :some_date AND start_time = :someTime AND endTime = :someTime
```

Currently I have this index

```
CREATE index resource_update_select on resource(resource_id, node_id, date);
```

So let's say there's multiple events

```
{"resource_id":1, "available": true, "date": "date1", start_time = "00:00", "end_time" = "23:59"}

{"resource_id":1, "available": true, "date": "date1", start_time = "23:00", "end_time" = "23:30"}


{"resource_id":2, "available": true, "date": "date2", start_time = "00:00", "end_time" = "23:59"}

{"resource_id":3, "available": true, "date": "date3", start_time = "00:00", "end_time" = "23:59"}
```

The above events gets picked up by different threads/pods, now when they get executed in parallel, they increase the Lock Wait as I can see from GCP Query Insights. I am not sure what m I doing wrong here? Should I do a select to check if any entry exists in the table and then update the record or is there something else m doing wrong?? Please help me out.

Note: The number of events i receive is huge, you can say per pod 10 threads can process and pods can scale up, upto 20 pods. So 200 threads can simultaneously process, i guess this is what causing the problem.

Update1:

The lock wait is responsible further to spike my DB's CPU upto 100%. This is where things get bad.

Comment: When do you start and end transactions?  And is there actually a problem?  If the time spent in lock waits would otherwise be spent in idle, then does it matter?

Comment: How is the DB CPU measured?  High lock waits should usually lead to low CPU, as waiting doesn't consume much CPU

Comment: I am not sure how is the DB CPU measured in GCP, need to check it once, but I see the CPU Spike going upto 70-100% while the lock wait has increased. I also found it weird.